# In VS Code: Is there any way to disable recently opened folders in the Mac Dock?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, dock

I know that I can clear recently opened via "File -> Open Recent -> Clear Recently Opened"

I also know that I can disable recently opened files for the quick search as explained here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/30770

What I want is to disable it in the dock preview (the dialog that opens when I right click on vs code in the docker)

Answer (score 2):

You can disable it by setting macOS System Settings -> General -> Recent items to "none"  I was also searching for this and found this solution

Answer (score 1):

On macOS Ventura 13.3.1, the setting is now in `System Settings -> Desktop & Dock -> Recent documents, applications and servers`. Set this to `None`